# Translate a child theme with pure PHP and gettext

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, translation, xgettext

I'm trying to translate a child theme of a parent theme that has all `msgstr` empty.

Therefore, I've created the file `de_DE.mo` using the "WordPress i18n tools" recommended in the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) together with `msgfmt`. I put the file into my child theme directory's subfolder `languages/child`.

To tell Wordpress about it, I added this to my functions.php where `mo_theme` is the parent theme's translation domain:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function () {
    load_theme_textdomain( 'mo_theme', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages/child' );
} );
```

However, the translation I've defined is not used. The .mo file looks OK, and other things defined in my functions.php have an effect.

I have used gettext in other contexts, but not yet together with Wordpress. Is there anything special I should care about?

**Example**

My parent theme defines `__('View your shopping cart', 'mo_theme')`.

In the .po file I've created, this is translated like this:

```
#: woocommerce/woocommerce-integration.php:76
msgid "View your shopping cart"
msgstr "Zum Warenkorb"
```

Comment: Stupid question, but it's the only step you've not mentioned and everything else look fine. Have you defined the `WP_LANG` constant...?

Comment: How are your gettext strings witin PHP? Can you show us some examples?

Comment: @StephenHarris Hehe. Your question wasn't too stupid. Now I `define('WPLANG', 'de_DE');` in my wp-config.php. However, this still does not help.

Comment: @cybmeta Thank you for asking back! I've added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Your code use [`load_theme_textdomain`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain). If you are in child theme and need to load translated strings, use function [`load_child_theme_textdomain`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_child_theme_textdomain). Please take a look this answer too [Override parent theme translation on child theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188820/18731).